# How to display only one element of an array in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

I have the following object with a "multimedia" array:

[image: nytimes api]

I only need one of the urls, but no idea how ot get it

```html
    <div
          class="card mb-3"
          style="max-width: 540px;"
          v-bind:key="news.artices"
          v-for="news in newsList" >
    
          <div class="row no-gutters">
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <div class="card-body">
    
               //this doesn't work
                <p v-for="image in news.multimedia" v-bind:key="image">
                    {{image[0].url}} 
                </p>
    
               //this works, but shows all
                <p v-for="image in news.multimedia" v-bind:key="image">
                    {{image.url}} 
                </p>
    
                <h5 class="card-title">{{news.title}}</h5>               
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to display only one element of the `multimedia` array, then you don't need to use `v-for` unnecessarily. You can simply use:

```
<p v-bind:key="image" v-if="news.multimedia && news.multimedia.length">
   {{ news.multimedia[0].url }} 
</p>
```

Also, you can use `v-if` to make sure this div is only rendered if `news.multimedia` has a valid value and it not an empty array.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `multimedia` is an array of objects, so you could do: `news.multimedia[0].url`.